# How do I import Immutable.js as an es6 module?

Tags: immutable.js, es6-modules

I'd like to use immutable.js in an es6 project using import. My bet is I'm missing the obvious, but:

- Is there an es6 module format? (couldn't find it in npm install nor github)
- If so, where? I tried the unpkg.com trick with ?module and no luck
- If not, how do I make my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is in a RC release:

> https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/releases/tag/v4.0.0-rc.3

Available as: https://unpkg.com/immutable@4.0.0-rc.9/dist/immutable.es.js

You can also use unpkg's ?module feature:  https://unpkg.com/immutable@4.0.0-rc.9?module